# Diffuse light direction

Tags: directx, hlsl, lighting

I'm learning a tutorial from Rastertek about diffuse light with DX 11, here's the shader code:

```
float4 LightPixelShader(PixelInputType input) : SV_TARGET
{
    float4 textureColor;
    float3 lightDir;
    float lightIntensity;
    float4 color;


    // Sample the pixel color from the texture using the sampler at this texture coordinate location.
    textureColor = shaderTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex);

    // Invert the light direction for calculations.
    lightDir = -lightDirection;

    // Calculate the amount of light on this pixel.
    lightIntensity = saturate(dot(input.normal, lightDir));

    // Determine the final amount of diffuse color based on the diffuse color combined with the light intensity.
    color = saturate(diffuseColor * lightIntensity);

    // Multiply the texture pixel and the final diffuse color to get the final pixel color result.
    color = color * textureColor;

    return color;
}
```

And I don't understand why to invert the direction, it says in a comment line "invert the light direction for calculations", why is it necesary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

@alariq is correct, assume you have this scenario:

[image]

The light is shining DOWN and LEFT.  The normal of the surface is UP and to the RIGHT.

If you just take the dot product:

```
float lightIntensity = saturate( dot( N, L ) )
```

The saturate function is going to clamp the value to being between 0 and 1.  So, that's going to be

```
lightIntensity = (0.5, 0.75) • (-0.75, -0.5) = -0.375 - 0.375 = -0.75
```

But oh no!  That will be clamped off to 0, and the point will appear in total darkness.  How sad.

So if you turn lightDir around,

```
float lightIntensity = saturate( dot( N, -L ) )
lightIntensity = 0.375 + 0.375 = 0.75
```

Oh, that works.  Why?

Well the light at the vertex should be most intense when lightDir is directly opposed to N.

[image]

But the dot product of two normalized vectors is **the cosine** of the angle between them

```
u • v = |u||v| cos(t)
```

If |u|=|v|=1, then

```
u • v = cos(t)
```

But cos(0) = 1, which should correspond with maximal illumination.  Here's what we'll do.  We'll turn lightDir AROUND, so then when -lightDir lines up perfectly with N, then lightDir is actually head-on with N.

All what we're doing is manipulating the vectors so that the dot product (which is actually the cosine of the angle between lightDir and N) gives a maximal value when lightDir is head-on with N.

Answer (score 3):

This is necessary to receive a correct sign of a dot product.
**lightIntensity** of a point depends on the angle between the two vectors: one is normal in a point of interest and second is a vector which goes from point of interest to light source.

That is, if the normal points at the light - intensity will be maximal. Imagine you are looking at the sun: your view vector is same as sun light direction, but with a different sign. So we need to inverse light direction to get correct dot product.

Your shader is for the case of direct light source (which is the approximation of a light source at infinity - like sun, and so intensity of a point depends only at its direction - not its position). In case of a point light formula might be more intuitive (assume **lightPos**, **pointPos** and **normal** in same space):

```
posToLightDir = normalize(lightPos - pointPos); // same as inverted lightDir in your case
lightIntensity = saturate(dot(normal, posToLightDir));
```

In case of directional light **pointPos** is not needed, so

```
// here normalize(lightPos) would be same as -lightDir
posToLightDir = normalize(lightPos);
```

You can search for Lambertian cosine Law, or [Lambertian Reflectance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertian_reflectance)